# Way to make Jenkins ignore stderr?

Tags: jenkins, stderr

I have a jenkins ci job that runs some shell commands (linux). Specifically I'm cd-ing into a git repo and using git add remote to make sure the remote is set before running other commands. Typically the remote is still there and there's stderr output saying "fatal: remote foo already exists" which is fine by me, but mr. Jenkins halts the job and marks it as failed.

How can I tell Jenkins to ignore this stderr or that it's expected? Or is there a smarter approach to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git add remote git_repo || true
```

this will return a 0 exit status

Answer (score 2):

The issue is Jenkins looks at exit codes and will fail the build if any of the targets you run returns a non-zero exit code.  So ignoring STDERR will not help.  Infact this is probably bad because any real failures at other places will not show up in the Jenkins logs if you hide STDERR.

the git command you are running is returning 1 if the remote already exists.  A work around is to wrap the git command and ignore the exit value and return your own exit value instead

Comment: Thanks, although @Keeto solved it, you explained it. Q: how do you "wrap the git command and ignore the exit value and return your own"?